# Benefit of using new Function in .map

Tags: node.js

What is the benefit of using a new Function being created inside a map Function()

Here is an example

```
const FunctionPropsList = [
    {
      id: 'SampleFun',
      srcPath: 'src',
      handler: 'index.handler'
    }
  ];
  
FunctionPropsList.map(props => new Function(props.id,{
    ...props}))
```

This example is taken from a stack deployment with cdk.

When I run that function I get Unexpected identifier for the new Function, which is anonymous

Comment: Is there a chance there is a class named `Function` exported from a npm package?

Comment: There is a construct import { Function } from '../lib/functions'; yes that new function is building a new object as defined from the import. thanks!